# sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

I want to remove Comma and getting this error -

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

Script I'm using is -

```
# convert from tsv to csv
sed 's/,/\g; s/\t/,/g' "${tsv_file}" >> "${csv_file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of a sed substitution (`s`) command is

```
s/pattern/replacement/flags
```

so in `s/,/\g; s/\t/,/g` it's interpreting `,` as the pattern, `\g; s` as the replacement, leaving `\t/,/g` as a sequence of flags. Since `\t` is not a valid flag, that's an error.

Presumably what you intended was

```
sed 's/,//g; s/\t/,/g' "${tsv_file}" >> "${csv_file}"
```

to remove all the commas and then convert tab separators to comma separators. However if you have a TSV file that contains commas, you might want to consider using a dedicated CSV formatting tool such as `csvformat` from the `csvkit` package (which will properly quote fields, allowing you to retain commas within a comma-separated format) rather than trying to handle them on an ad hoc basis.

Comment: When I tried above it got this error - /bin/bash: -c: line 37: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is : `sed 's/ReplaceThisText/ByThis/g'`

```
sed -e 's/,//g' -e 's/\t/,/g' "${tsv_file}" >> "${csv_file}"
# replace comma by nothing, then replace tab by comma
```

The `-e` option gives the ability to chain actions

```
   -e script, --expression=script
          add the script to the commands to be executed
```